.NET solution: how are project dependencies resolved for multi-targeted build?
I have a solution with several projects in net 9 (guess it will be the same for .net 6-8, so not important).
There I have project/assembly A with multi-targeted build: net9;net9.0-windows
Windows version contains some event log logging, which obviously is not supported on Linux or any other non-windows OS.
Then I have project/assembly B referencing A. It contains no Windows-specific code, though it references A, but the API there is the same doesn't matter what the build is. I set the build target to net9.
Finally, I have the executable project C. It is net9;net9.0-windows again, it doesn't reference A directly, but it does reference B.
I would like windows version of C to have windows version of A. Will the build be smart enough to resolve windows version of A? Or do I need to make B multi-targeted too, even though it has no platform-specific code?

Surely this is something that you can test for yourself fairly easily.

Yes, in a couple of hours or so, in reality it is a more complex solution than I described. In the end, when it comes to it, I will know the answer. But I'm interested in an "official" answer. Couldn't find documents about that.

It's clear how it should work, but I would also not be sure whether this works as expected. Of course, you could always change B to be also net9;net9-windows or have C reference A directly.

@PMF At the moment that's what I do, being extra-careful: changed B to multi-targeted. But that's not the cleanest option.
